# Correct usage of a list in a column value in a table?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

This is the structure of my JSON file that i'm working with.

```
{
  "date": "2015-11-11",
  "retailer_id": "CLD001",
  "orders": [
    {
      "products": [
        {
          "product_id": "53743443003",
          "quantity": 4,
          "unit_price": 42.71
        }
      ],
      "value": 170.84,
      "customer": {
        "id": 58
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To handle this Json file i created 3 separate classes to contain the information which are productsOrdered, OrderItems and RetailerOrders. It is saying that sql can't match the type to a generic system list?

```
 [Table]
    public class OrderItems : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        private List<ProductsOrdered> po = new List<ProductsOrdered>();
        private double TotalPrice;
        private int customer_id;

       ///this list is also throwing a error i'd suspect after the parent is fixed

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "products")]
        [Column]
```

///set up a list of products that have been ordered

```
 public List<ProductsOrdered> Productsordered
            {
                get { return po; }
                set
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Products Ordered");
                    po = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Products Ordered"); 
                }
            }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
        [Column]
        public double totalprice
        {
            get { return TotalPrice; }
            set {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Total Price");
                TotalPrice = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Total Price"); 
               }
        }


        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int customerid
        {
            get { return customer_id; }
            set {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Customer_ID");
                customer_id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Custome_ID");

                }
        }



        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                              new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanging != null)
            {
                PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
    }
```

///retailers order where the error is originating from  An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

```
  [Table]
    public class RetailOrders : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        private List<OrderItems> oi;
        private string retailer_id;
        private DateTime date;


       [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "retailer_id")]
        public string Retailer_id
        {
            get { return retailer_id; }
            set {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Retailer ID");
                retailer_id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Retailer ID");
                }
        }
```

more information on the error shows that it originated here, Unable to determine SQL type for 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SalesManagement.OrderItems]'. which makes me think i'm setting the column value wrongly

```
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "orders")]
        [Column]
        public List<OrderItems> OrderItems
        {
            get { return oi; }
            set {
                   NotifyPropertyChanging("OrderItems");
                   oi = value;
                   NotifyPropertyChanged("OrderItems"); 
                }
        }


        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")]
        [Column]
        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return date; }
            set {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("date");
                date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("date");
                }
        }



        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                              new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanging != null)
            {
                PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
    }
```

///this is my productsOrdered Table which contains a single object which has a ID, QUANITY AND UNIT PRICE

```
    [Table]
    public class ProductsOrdered : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        private string productID;
        private int quantity;
        private double unit_price;



        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "product_id")]
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public string ProductID
        {
            get { return productID; }
            set
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("product ID");
                  productID = value;
                  NotifyPropertyChanged("product ID");
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "quantity")]
        [Column]
        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return quantity; }
            set {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("quantity");
                quantity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("quantity");
            }
        }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "unit_price")]
        [Column]
        public double UnitPrice
        {
            get { return unit_price; }
            set {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("unit price");
                unit_price = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("unit price");
            }
        }



        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                              new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanging != null)
            {
                PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
    }
```

Through some investigation it is leading me to believe to use [ASSOCIATION] instead of [Column] once it gets to lists however i'm not sure on what the correct way to handle forming table

Comment: How about removing all unnecessary things to have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Your customerid JsonProperty is id, but in the JSON it's under customer and then id is under brackets, could that be causing other problems?

Comment: Can do but those classes are whats being used create the table

Comment: *It is saying...* -- What is "it"? You do have to turn this into an MCVE as suggested above. The code is very hard to read because of bad indentation, irrelevant (to the issue) attributes and white space. All these properties could be auto-properties.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing issues by trying to reuse the classes for JSON, MVVM and SQL.  It is far better to have different (but ultimately very similar) classes for serialisation, views and entities.

Comment: This looks like a comment instead an answer.

Comment: Maybe, but I think it is also the answer to the problem.

Comment: They are a several levels  of _problems_ in Q, the top one is that OP don't know how to write right questions.

Comment: To be honest i'm more confused now than when i posted the question. I thought it may have been because of the [Association] keyword but now i'm lost

Comment: This is one of the cases where you really need someone experienced, to sit with you and talk you through the issues.   Try splitting your classes into 'deserialising json', 'view models and UI notification, and 'database entities'.  You can add and remove fields in each class that is not required elsewhere (for example, database aren't interested in NotifyPropertyChanged, json classes don't care about [Table] etc).

Comment: Okay okay i understand now, it's better to have functionalities in separate methods otherwise we get the issue of having it clutter and not readable

Comment: @Darman, post your questions one by one. Also, also with code as simple as you can. Just code to illustrate your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve